# How do i receive serial data via bluetooth in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to receive serial data via Bluetooth but am unable to do so. Please suggest how I could do this.

A simple example as to how Bluetooth connection is established and data received.

Comment: what have you tried ? please be more specific on the help you need so that we can try to help .. for general android Bluetooth howto read below

Comment: Have a look at this link: http://bellcode.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/android-and-arduino-bluetooth-communication/ Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Bluetooth section in the DevGuide

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html

and eventually the Bluetooth chat example as well

- http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html